# Do we need fixed point combinators in C#?

Tags: c#, functional-programming, lambda

I was playing with recursive lambdas in C# and have found two approaches to do this on the web. One approach uses [fixed point combinator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y_combinator) and the other does not. In the code below f1 is built using combinator, and f2 is defined directly. My question is, do we need fixed point combinators in C# or the language already provides all we need, so we can leave them alone?

```
class Program
{
    static Func<T, T> F<T>(Func<Func<T,T>,Func<T,T>> f)
    {
        return x => f(F(f))(x);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Func<Func<int,int>,Func<int,int>> f = fac => x => x == 0 ? 1 : x * fac(x - 1);
        var f1 = F(f);

        Console.WriteLine(f1(5));

        Func<int, int> f2 = null;
        f2 = x => x == 0 ? 1 : x * f2(x - 1);

        Console.WriteLine(f2(5));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As we can give a name to a method, that means that the language already has the necessary support for recursion built into it.

Note that the second method given in your question involves changing the value of a variable after it has been introduced, making it not "pure" functional programming.
Y-combinator is only necessary if your system of functional calculus doesn't have a built-in notion of a function that can refer to its own definition by name before the definition is completely defined. C# has two ways to do that directly: 1. initially defining the function variable as null and 2. declaring an ordinary named method (by far the preferred technique).

Comment: What about for memoization of recursive functions?

Comment: I'd say the resulting ugliness means it is worse than just building memoization into a recursive function by hand (which isn't that hard to make fairly reusable).

Comment: Well yea, exactly. C# gets ugly real fast if you try to do any of this, so it's all impractical for the most part.

Answer (score 3):

I think it can be rather elegant with an extra utility class called Recursive as follows:

```
public static class Recursive {
            public static Func<R> Func<R>(
                Func<Func<R>, Func<R>> f) { 
                return () => f(Func(f))(); }
            public static Func<T1, R> Func<T1, R>(
                Func<Func<T1, R>, Func<T1, R>> f) { 
                return x => f(Func(f))(x); }
            public static Func<T1, T2, R> Func<T1, T2, R>(
                Func<Func<T1, T2, R>, Func<T1, T2, R>> f) {
                return (a1, a2) => f(Func(f))(a1, a2);
            }
            //And so on...
        }

class Program {

    static void Main(string[] args) {

        Console.WriteLine(
            Recursive.Func<int, int>(factorial =>
                x => x == 0 ? 1 : factorial(x - 1) * x
            ) 
            (10)
        );

        Console.WriteLine(
            Recursive.Func<int,int,int>(gcd =>
                (x,y) => 
                    x == 0 ? y:
                    y == 0 ? x:
                    x > y  ? gcd(x % y, y):
                    gcd(y % x, x)
            )
            (35,21)
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to declare your recursive Func delegates as static members:

```
static Func<int, int> Factorial = (n) => n <= 1 ? 1 : n*Factorial(n - 1);
```

Answer (score -2):

What does "need" mean? C# doesn't need them, as you shouldn't be attempting this sort of functional programming in C#. It's just a pathway to pain.

Memoizing a recursive function is one place you'd want a fixed point combinator. Compare this in [C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/wesdyer/archive/2007/02/05/memoization-and-anonymous-recursion.aspx) to [Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Memoization#Memoizing_fix_point_operator).

So, before C# "needs" this, it has a needs a lot of work to make this sort of programming reasonably practical.